# Using the last_value function on every column | Downfilling all nulls in a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table an individual level table, ordered by Person_ID and Date, ascending.  There are duplicate entries at the Person_ID level.  What I would like to do is "downfill" null values across every column -- my impression is that the last_value( | ignore nulls) function will work perfectly for each column.

A major problem is that the table is hundreds of columns wide, and is quite dynamic (feature creation for ML experiments).  There has to be a better way than to writing out a last_value statement for each variable, something like this:

```
SELECT last_value(var1) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_ID ORDER BY Date ASC
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as Var1,
       last_value(var2) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_ID ORDER BY Date ASC
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as Var2,
       ...
       last_value(var300) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_ID ORDER BY Date ASC
             RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as Var3
FROM TABLE
```

In summmary, I have the following table:

```
+----------+-----------+------+------+---+------------+
| PersonID | YearMonth | Var1 | Var2 | … |   Var300   |
+----------+-----------+------+------+---+------------+
|        1 |    200901 | 2    | null |   | null       |
|        1 |    200902 | null | 1    |   | Category 1 |
|        1 |    201010 | null | 1    |   | null       |
+----------+-----------+------+------+---+------------+
```

and desire the following table:

```
+----------+-----------+------+------+---+------------+
| PersonID | YearMonth | Var1 | Var2 | … |   Var300   |
+----------+-----------+------+------+---+------------+
|        1 |    200901 |    2 | null |   | null       |
|        1 |    200902 |    2 | 1    |   | Category 1 |
|        1 |    201010 |    2 | 1    |   | Category 1 |
+----------+-----------+------+------+---+------------+
```

Comment: You say "downfill" but your range partition includes `UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING`, which is not going to result in a "downfill".  Can you please clarify your requirement?

Comment: Apologies -- I am new to the last_value() function.  I think I want to remove unbounded following.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any great options for you, but here are two approaches you might look into.

#### OPTION 1 -- Recursive CTE

In this approach, you use a recursive query, where each child value equals itself or, if it is null, its parent's value.  Like so:

```
WITH 
ordered AS (
   SELECT yt.*
          row_number() over ( partition by yt.personid order by yt.yearmonth ) rn
   FROM   YOUR_TABLE yt),
downfilled ( personid, yearmonth, var1, var2, ..., var300, rn) as (
   SELECT o.*
   FROM   ordered o
   WHERE  o.rn = 1
   UNION ALL
   SELECT  c.personid, c.yearmonth, 
           nvl(c.var1, p.var1) var1,
           nvl(c.var2, p.var2) var2,
           ...
           nvl(c.var300, p.var300) var300
   FROM    downfilled p INNER JOIN ordered c ON c.personid = p.personid AND c.rn = p.rn + 1 )
SELECT * FROM downfilled
ORDER BY personid, yearmonth;
```

This replaces each expression like this:

```
last_value(var2) OVER (PARTITION BY Person_ID ORDER BY Date ASC
         RANGE BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) as Var2
```

with an expression like this:

```
NVL(c.var2, p.var2)
```

One downside, though, is that this makes you repeat the list of 300 columns twice (once for the 300 `NVL()` expressions and once to specify the output columns of the recursive CTE (`downfilled`).

#### OPTION 2 -- UNPIVOT and PIVOT again

In this approach, you `UNPIVOT` your `VARxx` columns into rows, so that you only need to write the `last_value()...` expression one time.

```
SELECT personid, 
       yearmonth, 
       var_column, 
       last_value(var_value ignore nulls)
          over ( partition by personid, var_column order by yearmonth ) var_value
FROM YOUR_TABLE
UNPIVOT INCLUDE NULLS ( var_value FOR var_column IN ("VAR1","VAR2","VAR3") ) )
SELECT * FROM unp
PIVOT ( max(var_value) FOR var_column IN ('VAR1' AS VAR1, 'VAR2' AS VAR, 'VAR3' AS VAR3 ) )
```

Here you still need to list each column twice.  Also, I'm not sure what performance will be like if you have a large data set.